# What does ufw logging?

Tags: bash, log, ufw

Normally `ufw` is disabled after a fresh setup. Recently I saw, ufw is activated. 
If I type `sudo ufw status verbose` the output is

```
status:activ
protocol: on (low)
```

But `/var/log/ufw.log` is empty. Someone knows why? Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Is your ufw logging switched on?

Comment: Yes, the logging is on (low).

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

to check if you are logging. If you are not you enable logging with ...

```
sudo ufw logging on
```

In case this does not start creating log files check with

```
sudo service rsyslog status
```

if rsyslog is running and if so do a

```
grep -i ufw /var/log/syslog
grep -i ufw /var/log/messages
grep -i ufw /var/log/kern.log
```

and check for errors regarding ufw (and act upon them ;) )

Comment: `grep`ing `syslog` and `kern.log` are without result. `messages` is a file I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (running a Raspbian 10 Pi, but it's the same in Ubuntu).

Enable medium logging:

```
sudo ufw logging medium
```

Try to generate some traffic from the Linux machine.
Then check if you have a log:

```
sudo find /var |grep ufw.log
```

To follow the log in real time:

```
tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
```

And to set the logging to "low" for less logging:

```
sudo ufw logging low
```

The "low" setting logs all blocked packets not matching the defined policy, as well as packets matching logged rules.